# How to use the twitter4j library?

Tags: java, twitter4j

I was overwhelmed by the amount of information on https://dev.twitter.com/docs and then I went to twitter4j and downloaded the library. I got a consumer key and secret by registering on their website. What are these for?

What I am trying to is get tweet text from certain twitter account( not my personal one but public one) and other information( account user, time and other stuff).

I couldn't find useful tutorial online. So please help me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The keys are so that your application can authenticate to the Twitter API. I put them in a properties file and made them available on the classpath. Once your application has authenticated, you will be able to use the API to get the account information you need. I don't know any good tutorials, but you could use an open source project I wrote as a reference if you like: https://github.com/rossh/gift-findr.

Comment: say i want to get the twitter text from https://twitter.com/ATT/. so far, i couldn't find any place to put this url as a parameter. i am very confused. if you can tell me that would be very helpful.

Comment: By text, I'm guessing you mean the text of a specific status update. If so, you probably want to do something like: `new TwitterFactory().getInstance().getHomeTimeline()` which will return you back a list of `Status` objects representing a list of status updates. You can then do `getText()` on a `Status` object which will return you the actual update text itself.

Comment: yes that is exactly what i want to do. but how to insert that twitter page that i want to analyse?

Comment: You could do something like `new TwitterFactory().getInstance().users().lookupUsers("screenName")` which will return you back a user then you just need to do `getStatus().getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to get hold of a `org.twitter4j.Twitter` object. Once you have that, you can do a great many operations - just inspect the interface for `org.twitter4j.Twitter`.

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance(twitter4JConfiguration);
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(oauthToken, oauthTokenSecret));
String screenName = twitter.getScreenName(); // Returns authenticating user's screen name.
User stephenfry = twitter.showUser("stephenfry"); // Returns extended information of a given user ...
List<User> friends = twitter.getFriendsList("stephenfry", -1L); // Returns a cursored collection of user objects ...
```

[This is a link to the javadoc for the `org.twitter4j.Twitter` interface](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/Twitter.html)

Comment: this will extract the twitter text by calling getscreenname?

Comment: You said "I got a consumer key and secret by registering on their website. What are these for?" My example shows how to get the `Twitter` object, from which you can do most things, including getting tweet text.

Comment: can you explain more? i am really confused by this. for twitter.setOAuthConsumer i have to put my consumer key and secret. forsetOAuthAccessToken i have to put my access token and secret. but where do i put my twitter page that i want to analyse?

Comment: I added some more examples to use the `org.twitter4j.Twitter` interface